# How do I overcome MSFT Word blocking UI while loading embedded external image?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, openxml, office-interop, com-interop

I am trying to insert an external image into a MSFT Word Document. We do not need the image to appear quickly, but we need MSFT Word to allow the user to continue using Word without blocking the UI while it is loading the external image since some users have reported the Word application blocking the UI for several seconds. I have attempted to do this with various methods:

- using Word Interop to insert an HTML file containing img tags where the src attribute is the URI to the external image
- creating a .DOTM file where one of the building blocks that I insert has an external relationship where the target is the URI to the external image
- creating a .DOTM file with an altchunk to an HTML file with an img tag where the src attribute is the URI to the external image

The problem with any of the mentioned approaches is that MSFT Word blocks the UI while it is trying to load the external image. Even when using a Word .DOTM template, the Word application blocks the UI while it compiles the .DOTM template.

I have tried to mitigate this issue by testing the network before using any of the above techniques, but various users who appear to have unstable network conditions still complain that MSFT Word sometimes blocks the UI while it is loading the image. We will also need to allow these users to embed these external images while the are offline eventually.

There are various reasons why the image must be external (e.g. single point of update for content editors) and we cannot load the image locally and then add a local reference (e.g. our authors need to easily transfer/share the document with the external image references intact).

For the users who do use our software that can generate a gallery of images that our users can insert, it's not so important that the image actually renders for them until they submit to their colleagues/clients. They would be fine with even the broken image that sometimes appears after Word has blocked for several seconds because they understand how the image would display when they finally push the document along their workflow.

I have attempted to preload the image in the WinINET cache, but it appears Word ignores that. Maybe there is an avenue there that I have not yet discovered? I am also exploring if there is a hack that tricks MSFT Office into not even trying, potentially by convincing it that there is no internet connection and allow it to render the broken image without blocking the UI for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's possible to set an Option in Word to "Show picture placeholders". That suppresses display of the actual pictures, but it applies to the entire application, not a particular document or picture, so I'm not sure that helps.

An approach that was often used "back in the day", when resources were at a premium, was to use the IncludePicture field (link to the picture) then LOCK the field so it couldn't update. You can choose whether to store the picture in the document or not using the \d switch. (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-IncludePicture-field-a3aac6dc-4e08-4d62-9aac-794279d02de9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

This would certainly allow the document to open more quickly as the picture would only be allowed to update when the field has been unlocked. So you'd need some kind of code or instructions to the user about enabling the field.

The major drawback, in my experience, is that recent versions of Word have a nasty tendancy to remove the field code and embed the picture in the document. As I recall, you need to keep the document in "compatibility mode" for 2007 (or maybe it's 2010) to prevent Word doing that.